# Is there a way to sing actual clear, nice two notes? (Polyphonic overtone singing)

Tags: theory, notation, technique, voice

So I found this two video

On polyphonic overtone singing,
I'm just wondering is there a way to actually sing good two notes that doesn't sound like a weird, creepy frog? (I'm just curious..)

Comment: Get two people.

Answer (score 1):

No. We only have one vocal apparatus each and the apparatus can only truly resonate at one pitch as a time.